# jQuery Accordion open collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

using jquery v1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.7.1

I have 1 tab control with 3 tabs in it. Each tab contains 1 accordion control.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#acc1').accordion({ collapsible: true, autoHeight: false });     

$('#acc1').accordion({ collapsible: true, autoHeight: false });     

$('#acc1').accordion({ collapsible: true, autoHeight: false });

$('#tabControl').tabs();

});
```

tabControl is not visible at page load. There is button that opens it.

```
$("#btnShow").bind("click", function() {
$('#tabControl').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

I can't find the way to have all accordion controls collapsed. Every time I show tabControl, accordions in it have first item always expanded.

I have tried this:

```
$('#acc1First').css('display', 'none');
$('#acc2First').css('display', 'none');
$('#acc3First').css('display', 'none');

$('#acc1First').slideUp();
$('#acc2First').slideUp();
$('#acc3First').slideUp();
```

but it bugges sometimes, first item have to be clicked 2 times to work properly etc.

Is there any way to initialize accordion control with all items collapsed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#acc1').accordion({ 
    collapsible: true, 
    autoHeight: false, 
    active: false 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created this one:

http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/creating-stylish-sliding-menu-with-jquery/