# jquery ui accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

Is it possible to make the jQuery UI Accordion first loads collapsed, so, no tab will load opened or active in default.

I know the option to make it collapsible but I want it to load totally collapsed then the user choses one tab.

I'm using the latest jquery 1.4.4 + jquery UI custom 1.8.6

Thanks.

Comment: not exactly on topic... but you could always roll your own... like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/HyqFs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use this:

[jQuery Accordion open collapsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817959/jquery-accordion-open-collapsed)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/collapse-accordion-all-at-once

Answer (score 3):

Set active to false

which is the same as setting each tab to display:none;

Answer (score 1):

Simply set all the according content elements to `display: none`. This will hide them all, until clicking the accordion title expands the content under it.

James

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
            heightStyle: "content", header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: false
        });
```